# What is the proper way to punctuate "but no"?

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions, commas, negation, periods

I'm trying to figure out the proper usage and punctuation of "but no". I think it's one of the following:

> - You figure I would have made at least one post about Arthur C. Clarke’s “2010” *during* 2010. But no, I missed the entire year.
> - You figure I would have made at least one post about Arthur C. Clarke’s “2010” *during* 2010. But, no. I missed the entire year.

Is one of those accurate, or is there a better way?

Comment: There shouldn't be a comma between "but" and "no". Aside from that, I think it's just a matter of style.

Comment: What @PeterShor said.

Comment: What @PeterShor & Robusto said. But after leafing through a few pages of **"but no I"** in Google Books, I would just say a comma between "no" and "I" seems by far the most popular choice. Alternatives include a period, semicolon, dash, and exclamation mark - all of which seem acceptable to me in context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I never thought about trying to search in Google Books. I spent a little time trying to search the web. That wasn't at all fruitful. I'll remember your Google Books trick in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you're worrying about the correct placement of a comma in a situation which flouts the grade school rule, "do not begin a sentence with a conjunction like *and* or *but*".

What you have here is a casual narrative:

*You figure I would have made at least one post about Arthur C. Clarke’s “2010” during 2010. But no. I missed the entire year.*

This is not formal writing but prose. An art form. (Is it correct to paint it in watercolor, or should you use oil? Acrylic?)

Hey look, I used "An art form" as a sentence. A fragment! No predicate or anything. Oops, I made like Britney Spears and did it again.

Comment: Nevertheless, writing a fragment as if it were a sentence is somewhat of a "big deal", so I would not waste this device on "But no". "But no" is really asking to be joined to the explanation which it introduces.

Comment: Everyone here thinks there should be no comma after *But*. Fine. What about the first version? Comma (not period) after *no*? What's wrong with that?

Comment: I personally would prefer the comma because "But no" doesn't stand alone all that well. It's a phrase which introduces whatever follows. It's not too dissimilar from "Hey Jack, come here" versus "Hey Jack. Come here.".  A period creates a dramatic effect. If you don't want that effect, don't use it. I think there is a difference if you read the two examples out loud. The period denotes a pause after a thought, which calls for a pause in speech. This is not really a matter of what is correct, but of what effect you want.

Comment: @Kaz, this is for my blog. I tend to write it like I speak. Lots of official grammar mistakes. I generally avoid the starting with "But". In this case I liked the tone of it for emphasis. The example you provided with the dramatic effect of "Hey Jack. Come here." is where I was headed with this one. This answers the heart of what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the others that it's a matter of style.  My style would be not to use a comma at all and replace it with a dash.  I'm not sure it's "dramatic" enough to warrant them by [Grammar Girl's definition](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/dashes-parentheses-commas.aspx), but it's nonetheless what I would do.

> You figure I would have made at least one post about Arthur C. Clarke’s “2010” during 2010. But no – I missed the entire year.

Comment: I like that. It's a little more emphasis than I want for this one, but I'll keep it in my bag of tricks. Thanks.